# Multiple templates for the same view of a custom component

Tags: custom-component, view

In my custom component, I would like to have multiple slightly different templates for the same view.

Something like

```
com_things/
...
 - views/
   - thing/
       ...
   - things/
     - tmpl/
         tabs.php
         accordion.php
         default.php
         default.xml
       view.html.php
```

In this example, the idea is that `default` template, `accordion` template and `tabs` template all use the data prepared in `views/things/view.html.php`, displaying it in slightly different ways.

The data should be displayed in the right template according to the url from which it's accessed, for example `index.php?option=com_things&view=things&tmpl=tabs`.

I've been playing with this for a while and looking for documentation, but I'm not being able to implement this feature. 
Shouldn't be enough to just create the `tabs.php` and `accordion.php` file, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue, I'm adding it here for future references.

Yes, it's enough to add the additional templates under the directory `com_things/views/things/tmpl/`.

The problem in the question was that I was using the wrong URL:

it should be

`index.php?option=com_things&view=things&layout=tabs`

instead of

`index.php?option=com_things&view=things&tmpl=tabs` .